# How to populate Rich Text Box Line By line with txt? vb

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I'm trying to populate a rich text box line by line with txt file... without result!

This is the result that would like to get:

1. House 2. Dog 3. Cat 4. Etc

each one in a row below the other

Any help would be great! 
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple brother :

```
Private Sub FillRichTextBoxFromFile(ByVal path As String)
        Try
            If IO.File.Exists(path) Then
                Using sr As New IO.StreamReader(path)
                    Dim s As String = ""
                    Dim i As Integer = 1
                    While Not sr.EndOfStream
                        s += CStr(i) + ". " + sr.ReadLine + vbNewLine
                        i += 1
                    End While
                    RichTextBox1.Text = s
                End Using
            Else
                MsgBox("Oooops, File not found !!!")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this

```
    Dim fileContents() As String

    If Not My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\New.txt") Then

        MsgBox("File Not Found")
        Exit Sub

    End If

    RichTextBox1.Text = vbNullString

    fileContents = Split(My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\New.txt"), vbNewLine)

    For i = 0 To fileContents.Count - 1

        RichTextBox1.Text += i + 1 & ". " & fileContents(i) & vbNewLine

    Next
```